# How to test next part of code when the request object has been mocked?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have some a Python function written this way:

```
    def verify_secondary_hostnames(self, publishedName, hostnames):
        cname = self.get_cname(publishedName)
        edge_ip = requests.get('http://{}'.format(cname)).headers['X-Edge-IP']
        for hostname in hostnames:
            headers = {"host": hostname}
            data = requests.head("http://{}".format(edge_ip), headers=headers)
            data.raise_for_status()
```

The unit test that I have tried to write for it looks like this:

```
    @patch("requests.get")
    @patch("requests.head")
    @patch("FrontEnd.FrontEnd.get_cname")
    def test_verify_secondary_hostnames(self, mock_get_cname, mock_head, mock_get):
        mock_get_cname.return_value = "hulahoop"
        mock_get.return_value.headers = {"X-Edge-IP": "hulahoop"}
        self.fe.verify_secondary_hostnames('publishedName', ['hostname'])
        self.assertEqual(mock_head.call_args,
                         call('http://hulahoop', headers={'host': 'hostname'}))
```

In this test the last part `raise_for_status` which actually does this:

```
def raise_for_status(self):
        """Raises stored :class:`HTTPError`, if one occurred."""

        http_error_msg = ''

        if 400 <= self.status_code < 500:
            http_error_msg = '%s Client Error: %s' % (self.status_code, self.reason)

        elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
            http_error_msg = '%s Server Error: %s' % (self.status_code, self.reason)

        if http_error_msg:
            raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

I can't do it here since I have already mocked the `requests.head`. How can I write my test to cover for that as well ? What I mean by "cover" here is that since the object is a mock object, How can I make it `raise_for_status` ? Do I have to create a mock method to do that or emulate a raise in my test ?

**Edit: This is the latest test I have with the problems outlined:**

```
@patch("requests.get")
@patch("requests.head")
@patch("FrontEnd.FrontEnd.get_cname")
@patch("requests.models.Response.raise_for_status")
def test_verify_secondary_hostnames(self, mock_raise,
                                    mock_get_cname, mock_head, mock_get):
    mock_get_cname.return_value = "hulahoop"
    mock_get.return_value.headers = {"X-Edge-IP": "hulahoop"}
    mock_head.return_value.status_code = 200
    self.fe.verify_secondary_hostnames('publishedName', ['hostname'])
    self.assertEqual(mock_head.call_args,
                     call('http://hulahoop', headers={'host': 'hostname'}))
    mock_head.raise_for_status.called <=== False here
    mock_head.reset_mock()
    mock_head.return_value.status_code = 400
    self.fe.verify_secondary_hostnames('publishedName', ['hostname'])
    mock_head.raise_for_status.called <=== Still false here.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your unit test:

```
mock_data = mock.MagicMock()
mock_data.status_code = 200 # TODO (Low Kian Seong): Test raise_for_status
mock_head.return_value = mock_data
...

mock_data.raise_for_status.assert_called_once_with()
```

Comment: This won't work because even for the status_code of say 200, the `raise_for_status` is still called. There is no way of differentiating them too since they are both called without argument.s

Comment: @low-kian-seong See my edit. Also please edit your post to be more descriptive.